# Extending object with splat and do

Tags: livescript

Minor thing but wondering if someone can suggest a better syntax to extend an existing object using a splat, but without using curly braces? My main purpose is to keep indented style while passing the extended object to a function. This has the correct behavior:

```
base-obj =
  old-prop: \value

do-something {
  ...base-obj
  extended-prop: \value
}
```

But can the curly braces be eliminated somehow? 'Do' doesn't work:

```
old-obj =
  old-prop: \value

do-something do
  ...old-obj
  new-prop: \value

  # do-something will only see new-prop
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you want is `with`:

```
do-something base-obj with do
  extended-prop: \value
```

From [LiveScript 1.3.1 operators' docs](http://livescript.net/#operators):

> The infix with (aka the cloneport) combines the clone and property copy operators for easy object creation. It is equivalent to ^^obj <<< obj2. Remember that the clone operator creates a prototypical clone, and prototypes are not serialized in JSON.

Comment: It does work. Thought I tried this before but now I realize that I got the wrong result because of the interpreter on livescript.net which evaluated the return value of do-something incorrectly (not sure why). To see what I mean, paste this code into livescript.net http://jsbin.com/hibahafoga/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: That's because the output on livescript.net is being serialized to JSON. "Remember that the clone operator creates a prototypical clone, and prototypes are not serialized in JSON.". Try this: http://jsbin.com/gejakucoyu/2/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I found <<< which will get the job done but in a somewhat roundabout way:

```
do-something {} <<< base-obj <<<
  extended-prop1: \value1
  extended-prop2: \value2
```

**Update:** modified to prevent side-effect change to base-obj, based on @homam's suggestion.

Comment: `{} <<< base-obj <<< extended-prop: \value`

Comment: `extended-prop: \value <<< base-obj`

Comment: @blvz seems obvious but doesn't work. compiles to { extendedProp: import$('value', baseObj) }

Comment: @homam good point, didn't think about the order of evaluation. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using `do`:

```
# new object can overwrite old-obj
do-something do
  old-obj <<<
    new-prop: \value
    another: \content


# old-obj can overwrite new object
do-something do
  do
    new-prop: \value
    another: \content
  <<< old-obj
```